# Inquiry in Bootstrapping

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made a bootstrap class which holds the redirecting and getting the parameters from the URL.

```
class Bootstrap
{
    private $controller;
    private $action;
    private $request;

    public function __construct($request){
        $this->request = $request;
        if ($this->request['controller'] == '') {
            $this->controller = 'home';
        } else {
            $this->controller = $this->request['controller'];
        }

        if ($this->request['action'] == '') {
            $this->action = 'index';
        } else {
            $this->action = $this->request['action'];
        }
        echo $this->controller;
    }
}
```

I've changed my domain from localhost to php.dev. Now the problem is that whenever i enter something in the url it echo only the "index" or the action and even I put something in the action it still echo "index".  For example: I've entered php.dev/users/ it should echo the word "users" the controller. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z)]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-z)-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$3&id=$5 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I used it in my project, it works as it should. If the problem persists, make sure that $request is filled correctly when passing it to the class.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help mate. Really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I just realized, when I entered php.dev only it echo index.php not home?

Comment: Try to add this lines before rule:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`